# Split a large csv file into multiple csv files according to the size in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a large CSV file and I want to split it with respect to size and the header should be in every file.

For example, I have this 1.6MB file and I want the child files shouldn't be more than 512KB. So practically the parent file should have 4 child file.
Tried with the below simple program but the file is splitting with blank child files.

```
    function  csvSplitter {

        $csvFile = "D:\Test\PTest\Dummy.csv";
        $split = 10;
        $content = Import-Csv $csvFile;
        $start = 1;
        $end = 0;
        $records_per_file = [int][Math]::Ceiling($content.Count / $split);
        for($i = 1; $i -le $split; $i++) { 

            $end += $records_per_file;
            $content | Where-Object {[int]$_.Id -ge $start -and [int]$_.Id -le $end} | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Test\PTest\Destination\file$i.csv" -NoTypeInformation;
            $start = $end + 1;

        }   
}csvSplitter
```

The logic for the size of the file is yet to write.

[image]
[image]

Tried to add both the files but I guess there is no option to add files.

Comment: You CSV file doesn't seem to contain an `Id` column

Comment: That's correct it doesn't contain any Id as column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this takes a slightly different path to a solution. [*grin*]

it ...

- loads the CSV as a plain text file
- saves the 1st line as a header line
- calcs the batch size from the total line count & the batch count
- uses array index ranges to grab the lines for each batch
- combines the header line with the current batch of lines
- writes that out to a text file

the reason for such a roundabout method is to save RAM. one drawback to loading the file as a CSV is the sheer amount of RAM needed. just loading the lines of text requires noticeably less RAM.

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$InFileName = 'LargeFile.csv'
$InFullFileName = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $InFileName

$BatchCount = 4

$DestDir = $env:TEMP
$OutFileName = 'LF_Batch_.csv'
$OutFullFileName = Join-Path -Path $DestDir -ChildPath $OutFileName

#region >>> build file to work with
#    remove this region when you are ready to do this with your test data OR to do this with real data
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $InFullFileName))
    {
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:APPDATA -Recurse -File |
        Sort-Object -Property Name |
        Select-Object Name, Length, LastWriteTime, Directory |
        Export-Csv -LiteralPath $InFullFileName -NoTypeInformation
    }
#endregion >>> build file to work with

$CsvAsText = Get-Content -LiteralPath $InFullFileName
[array]$HeaderLine = $CsvAsText[0]
$BatchSize = [int]($CsvAsText.Count / $BatchCount) + 1

$StartLine = 1

foreach ($B_Index in 1..$BatchCount)
    {
    if ($B_Index -ne 1)
        {
        $StartLine = $StartLine + $BatchSize + 1
        }
    $CurrentOutFullFileName = $OutFullFileName.Replace('_.', ('_{0}.' -f $B_Index))
    $HeaderLine + $CsvAsText[$StartLine..($StartLine + $BatchSize)] |
        Set-Content -LiteralPath $CurrentOutFullFileName
    }
```

there is no output on screen, but i got 4 files named `LF_Batch_1.csv` thru `LF_Batch_4.csv` that contained the 4our parts of the source file as expected. the last file has a slightly smaller number of rows, but that is what happens when the row count is not evenly divisible by the batch count. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

function Split-Csv {

    param (
        [string]$filePath,
        [int]$partsNum
    )

    # Use generic lists for import/export
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$contentImport = @()
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$contentExport = @()

    # import csv-file
    $contentImport = Import-Csv $filePath

    # how many lines per export file
    $linesPerFile = [Math]::Max( [int]($contentImport.Count / $partsNum), 1 )
    # start pointer for source list
    $startPointer = 0
    # counter for file name
    $counter      = 1

    # main loop
    while( $startPointer -lt $contentImport.Count ) {
        # clear export list
        [void]$contentExport.Clear()
        # determine from-to from source list to export
        $endPointer = [Math]::Min( $startPointer + $linesPerFile, $contentImport.Count )
        # move lines to export to export list
        [void]$contentExport.AddRange( $contentImport.GetRange( $startPointer, $endPointer - $startPointer ) )
        # export
        $contentExport | Export-Csv -Path ($filePath.Replace('.', $counter.ToString() + '.' ) ) -NoTypeInformation -Force
        # move pointer
        $startPointer = $endPointer
        # increase counter for filename
        $counter++
    }

}

Split-Csv -filePath 'test.csv' -partsNum 7
```

Comment: If I would like to exclude the header, do I need to start the "startCounter" from 1 and few of the files are not having any header and they are giving me 
Import-Csv : The member "<column_name>" is already present.

Comment: ($contentExport | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
Set-Content -Path ($filePath.Replace('.', $counter.ToString() + '.' ) )

Answer (score -1):

try running [this script](http://%20https://github.com/coderayway/SplitLarge-CSVfiles/blob/main/Test%20Run.ps1):

```
$sw = new-object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$sw.Start()

$FilePath = $HOME +'\Documents\Projects\ADOPT\Data8277.csv' 
$SplitDir = $HOME +'\Documents\Projects\ADOPT\Split\' 


CSV-FileSplitter -Path $FilePath -PartSizeBytes 35MB -SplitDir $SplitDir #-Verbose 


$sw.Stop()
Write-Host "Split complete in " $sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds "seconds"
```

I created this for files larger than 50GB files